# Intellij IDEA: How to set up Imported Maven Project Correctly?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jooq

I downloaded a maven project (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ) into Intellij IDEA, as I want to debug the spring-boot testcase `org.jooq.example.spring.QueryTest`.

I did as described in the example `README.md`:

```
$ pwd 
/path/to/checkout/dir
$ ls
jOOQ jOOQ-meta jOOQ-codegen ...
$ mvn clean install
...
$ cd jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-boot-example
...
$ mvn clean install
```

I set the java source and test directories manually in the IntelliJ project (right mouse click, `mark directory as...`) for the java example directory and the java test directory for `jooq-spring-boot`.

Now I still have a lot of errors, as the further setup of imports etc. seems to be missing. See screenshot.
[image]
What do I have to do to remove these errors?

Is there any possibility to automate these steps like setting the test and source directory manually?

Comment: Did you import your project as a Maven project?

Comment: You can import the maven project. Use **File** -> **New** -> **Project From Existing Sources...**. Then pick the "maven" option.

Comment: @nullpointer I imported it via File - New - Project from Version Control - Git

Comment: @teppic and should I set "Search for projects recursively" in the import dialogue?

Comment: @user4450574 yes you can

Comment: Usually not. But I'm not sure how your repo is structured.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to import this same project from github and set up the IntelliJ project correctly within 2 minutes, and here's how:

If you didn't do it already, check out the project from github. If you have an intellij project from before - start over, and check it out again.

`VCS` -> `Check out from Version Control` -> `GitHub` -> https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ

Now, after it checks out the project, this is important, when the next dialog window comes, hit `CANCEL`. You do *not* want to configure all the modules and source locations manually in the dialog box that follows "Check out from Version Control".

Instead, go to `File` -> `Open...` and choose the folder where you just checked out jOOQ from version control.

This will "force" IntelliJ to automatically create a project based on the structure of the pom.xml. It works - I tried it just now, with IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.2 (upgrade if your version is too old).

Good luck.

[image: fresh IntelliJ project created for jOOQ]

Edit:

Indeed I saw the same errors when i looked at `QueryTest` class in `jOOQ-spring-example`.

It's really simple - you just need to build the module. The generated sources will provide the needed classes (they will no longer be red).

You will notice that the `jOOQ-examples` folder does not have a pom.xml, so you will need to set up the `pom.xml` in `jOOQ-spring-example` manually - right click on the `pom.xml` and select `+ Add as Maven Project`.

You might need to click `Reimport All Maven Projects` so that the source and test roots get marked blue and green in the `jOOQ-spring-example` structure in the project pain.

Then, in the maven window, find `jOOQ Spring Example` and build it with maven (Lifecycle -> install). Once it builds, the generated sources will be available under `jOOQ-spring-example/target/generated-sources` - the `jooq-h2` folder should be marked blue as a generated source root.

Go back to `QueryTest` and you can see the classes in the imports are no longer red.

You should be good to go now :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately, the class `org.jooq.example.spring.QueryTest` still has the same errors.